# How to impose cascade delete or cascade set null on two foreign keys in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables.

```
create table A 
(
    idA int primary key,
    .
    .
)

create table B 
(
   idA int, 
   idB int primary key,
   .
   .
   Foreign key (idA) A (idA) ON DELETE CASCADE
)

create Table AB 
(
    idA int,
    idB int,
    .
    .
    Foreign key (idA) A (idA),
    Foreign key (idB) B (idB)
)
```

The app is controlling data in such a way that,  in **table AB**, either one of `idA` and `idB` will set other going to be null.

How to impose something like this

```
Foreign key (idA) A (idA) ON DELETE CASCADE,
Foreign key (idB) B (idB) ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

or

```
Foreign key (idA) A (idA) ON DELETE CASCADE,
Foreign key (idB) B (idB) ON DELETE SET NULL,
```

or

```
Foreign key (idA) A (idA) ON DELETE SET NULL,
Foreign key (idB) B (idB) ON DELETE SET NULL,
```

In each case I am getting an error:

> SQL Error [1785] [S0000]:
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK__inventory_except__2022C2A6' on table 'inventory_exception' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Comment: you should use alter table x before your queries

Comment: Leave the foreign keys with no action and use instead of delete triggers to delete the data in the child table.

Comment: Why even ON DELETE SET NULL on both foreign keys not working. Even if I am able to do that without trigger i will be good.

Comment: @atabrizi I am directly giving it in the create table ddl .

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
create table A (
    idA int primary key
);

create table B (
   idB int primary key
);

create Table AB (
    idA int,
    idB int,
    check (idA is null and idB is not null or idA is not null and idB is null),
    Foreign key (idA) A (idA) on delete cascade,
    Foreign key (idB) B (idB) on delete cascade
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=43a4bcca0ed7b7266d6112f6879350b8) is a db<>fiddle.

You would seem to have other constraints that are causing the problem.  If so, your question doesn't have enough information to really explain the problem.

Comment: yes u r correct it worked. i tried to simplify the question didn't check the simplified version is already working.  I have updated actual scenario where B also has A's primary key as foreign key. Can u suggest something in this case.